# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CertificateName'

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.0.2 in the local but when I try to install it using PS script I get below error (in screenshot) in the starting itself while running the command `Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose`, available in the script.

[image]

But in my script I can see that parameter 'CertificateName' is available.

Below is the script that I am using

```
$prefix = "mylocal.ecom" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\SitecoreAssets"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$InstallDirectory = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\"
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\solr-6.6.2-8983" 
$SolrService = "Solr-6.6.2-8983" 
$SqlServer = "XXXXXXXX\SQLEX2016" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword="localsys@123" 


#$solrParams = @{     
#    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
#    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
#    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
#    SolrService = $SolrService     
#    CorePrefix = $prefix 
#} 

#Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 
 
#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
   CertificateName = "mylocal.ecom.xconnect_client" 
    } 
    
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 
 
#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose 
 
#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    InstallDirectory = $InstallDirectory
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose 
 
#install solr cores for sitecore $solrParams = 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 
 
#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"  
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    InstallDirectory = $InstallDirectory
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

I have SIF version 1.2.1 installed, although I tried to install 2.0.0 but the error was same so I uninstalled 2.0.0 and kept only 1.2.1 because with Sitecore 9.0.2 SIF 1.2.1 should work fine.

Please let me know what is the main issue in this?

Comment: Where is your `@certParams` defined?

Comment: @MarkCassidy you can see it in the script the variable is available as $certParams = @{...........}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed that .JSON files were corrupted by newline characters used by the editor I  use for opening the files so I replaced the following .JSON files by again extracting from the zip (shown in the screenshot).

[image]

After that the actual error regarding parameter name "CertificateName" was resolved but again new error was coming with same error sentence, but this time parameter name was "InstallDirectory"

So, not sure what was wrong in the script, but I googled few other blogs and then found another script as following:

```
Import-Module SitecoreFundamentals

Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework

#define parameters 
$prefix = "sc9u2" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\resourcefiles\"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8984/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\Solr\solr-6.6.2\" 
$SolrService = "Solr" 
$SqlServer = ".\" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword= "S1t3c0r3" 

#$solrParams = @{     
#    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
#    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
#    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
#    SolrService = $SolrService     
#    CorePrefix = $prefix 
#} 

#Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 
 
#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    } 
    
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 
 
#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose 
 
#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore * (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose 
 
#install solr cores for sitecore $solrParams = 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 
 
#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore * (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"  
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName    
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

By using this Sitecore installed perfectly without any error.